# What to do to install ubuntu or not?

Tags: boot, dual-boot

"This computer currently has windows boot manager and ubuntu 22.04.2 lts on it. What would you like to do?"

The reason behind this was before this i change my motherboard, and fresh install the windows. So, i cannot boot to my ubuntu as there is no boot option to it.

So what i need to do ?

1. Erase ubuntu and resintall ?
2. Erase disk and install ubuntu ?
3. something else ?

Note that previously i have install ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on external HDD.

Comment: You use boot-repair to fix Ubuntu.

Comment: there is only one person in the entire world that can tell YOU what YOU should do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: New UEFI based systems have UEFI boot entries in UEFI and in ESP. Ubuntu whether internal or external puts boot files into ESP on first drive. With external drives you should have an ESP - efi system partition on external drive & grub installed to that ESP. UEFI then can boot drive, but it will not be an "ubuntu" entry. UEFI normally forgets entries if drive is removed. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 Add ESP with gparted  & reinstall grub to external drive, either manually or with Boot-Repair.

Answer (score 1):

The choice is yours, depending on what you prefer.

*Erase ubuntu and resintall* will erase the existing Ubuntu installation and reinstall that one, leaving anything else on the drive in place.

*Erase disk and install ubuntu* will fully empty the disk and dedicate the entire disk to a new Ubuntu installation.

*something else* this option allows more experienced users to do something else, for example change partitioning, install on a different partition, etc.